# About tqdm in deep learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, tqdm

I was using tqdm to show the process when running the code. However, i failed and the result on the console keep the same
[the consle view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI1sQ.png)

here is my code:

```
    for epoch in range(epoch_num):
        print("Training epoch{}".format(epoch + 1))
        pbar = tqdm(train_dataloader)
        for step, batch in enumerate(pbar):
            if step == 5:
                torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join(save_path, 'best_param.bin'))
                print(" Model Saved")
                print("Stopped Early")
                break
            model.train()
            inputs = {
                'input_ids': batch[0],
                'attention_mask': batch[1],
                'token_type_ids': batch[2],
                'labels': batch[3]
            }
            outputs = model(**inputs)
            loss, results = outputs
            optimizer.zero_grad()  # ??
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            loss_list.append(loss.item())
        pbar.set_description('Batch loss{:.3f}'.format(loss.item()))
```

Comment: Dataset type is TensorDataset in pytorch

Answer (score 2):

You have the pbar variable which is responsible for the loop progress bar defined within the loop, also you are not updating it, so what you are doing is that each iteration you are basically recreating a progress bar that is at 0%

What you should do is have the tqdm track the progress of the epochs in the for loop line like this:

```
for epoch in tqdm(range(epoch_num)):
```

This way it takes an iterable and iterates over it and creates the progress bar according to it.

Also make sure you are importing tqdm like this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

Comment: Yeah, yeah, you're right. I have got this right this time by changing the code. By the way, iterate over the data batch is OK in fact.